# What is externalEditorEnabled do?

Tags: plone-4.x, plone-5.x

I have key error with externalEditorEnabled.

It appears in Products.ATContentTypes.

I think it was used Plone4.

But I found script at Plone5.

- Products.CMFPlone-5.0.8-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_scripts/externalEditorEnabled.py
- Products.CMFPlone-5.0.8-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_scripts/external_edit.py

Comment: I found a file list in plone_scripts. But I cant understand what mean. "it looks there are some low hanging fruits around." https://community.plone.org/t/scripts-in-plone-to-get-rid-of/2892

Comment: "low hanging fruits" means a function that is made easily. http://d.hatena.ne.jp/iteigo/20070218

Answer (score 0):

Goto Plone Skins Tool at /Plone/portal_skins

http://0.0.0.0:8086/Plone/portal_skins/manage_skinLayers

And add Layers.

- custom
- archetypes
- ATContentTypes
- cmfeditions_views
- CMFEditions
- mimetypes_icons
- PasswordReset
- plone_ecmascript
- plone_wysiwyg
- plone_prefs
- plone_templates
- plone_form_scripts
- plone_scripts
- plone_images
- plone_content
- plone_login